# RSpec how to mock method inside another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In `application_controller` I've got two methods which results I want to test in a `maintenance_mode_controller_specs`. How to create mock `maintenance_mode_active?` which will return `false` to use it inside `check_maintenance?`?

`application_controller.rb`
    before_action :check_maintenance?

```
private

def check_maintenance?
  if maintenance_mode_active? == true
    redirect_to maintenance_mode
  elsif request.fullpath.include?(maintenance_mode_path)
    redirect_to :root
  end
end

def maintenance_mode_active?
  # do sth ...
  mode.active?
end
```

`maintenance_mode_controller_spec.rb`

```
context 'when maintenance mode is active' do
  let(:maintenance_mode?) { instance_double(ApplicationController) }

  before do
    allow(ApplicationController).to receive(:maintenance_mode_active?).and_return(false)
  end

  it 'redirect to root path' do
    expect(described_class).should redirect_to(maintenance_mode_path)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`maintenance_mode_active` is an instance method and you stub it on the class level. You need to use [`allow_any_instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:maintenance_mode_active?).and_return(false)
end
```

Comment: I cannot use `allow_any_instance_of` because of rubocop, is there any alternative?